# Solve equation with exponential and sine.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I want to solve the following equation but I don't know the right way, I've tried some things such as converting sines to their exponentials through euler's equation but still I can't go on. Any ideas?
Here is the equation:
$$\sin (b-u) + \sin u \ e ^{ \frac{-b}{0.333} } = 0 $$

Where $u$ is known variable and is equal to $20$ degrees. The variable that has to be found is $b$ .

Comment: I have not tried to solve it, but this might help: $\sin (b-u) = -\sin (u-b) = -\frac{e^{i(b-u} - e^{-i(b-u}}{2i}$

Answer (score 0):

Working with radians and whole numbers, you are looking for the zero's of function
$$f(b)=\sin \left(b-\frac{\pi }{9}\right)+e^{-3 b} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)$$ which, being transcendental, will not show analytical solution.

I suppose that you already noticed the trivial solution $b=0$. But, graphing, we notice another one close to $0.05$.

Using Newton method, you would get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & b_n \\
 0 & 0.050000000 \\
 1 & 0.053424485 \\
 2 & 0.053215971 \\
 3 & 0.053215198 \\
 4 & 0.053215198
\end{array}
\right)$$

Let us be even more lazy : the root being small, use Taylor expansion to get
$$f(b)=b \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{9}\right)\right)+5 b^2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)+O\left(b^3\right)$$ which gives, as an *estimate*,
$$b=\frac{1}{5} \left(3-\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)\right)\approx 0.0505045$$

If we add the next term of the expansion
$$f(b)=b \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{9}\right)\right)+5 b^2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-b^3 \left(\frac{9}{2}
   \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)+\frac{1}{6} \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{9}\right)\right)+O\left(b^4\right)$$ which is a quadratic in $b$. Solving it, the *estimate* would be $0.053324$.

To polish the root, one iteration of Newton method would probably suffice.

Comment: This is only one solution, approximatively. $$x=0$$ is the obosouly trivial solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. You are wrong.